# resolving variables from global scope in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

I am trying to better understanding scoping in python.  I have the following toy example:

```
a = 1
print "in global: " + str(a)

def g():
    a += 1
    print "in g(): " + str(a)


def f():
    a += 1
    print "in f(): " + str(a)
    g()

f()
```

I expected this to run and print out `1` then `2` then `2` again. However, instead I get en error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

I would have thought both `g()` and `f()` would pull `a` from the global scope. Incorrect?

UPDATED:
Thanks for the answers but what isn't clear is this: if I would like to just read the global variable `a` and assign it to a local variable that I create, also named `a` is that possible?

The reason I am doing this is I'm trying to figure out if `g()` inherits the scope of `f()` when it is called or the global scope where it is defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to change `a` in outer scope of functions, `a` is not in the scope of current functions, that's why you are getting such an error, because your functions know nothing about `a`. If you want to change `a` from within functions you need to use `global':

```
a = 1
print "in global: " + str(a)

def g():  
    global a
    a += 1
    print "in g(): " + str(a)


def f():
    global a
    a += 1
    print "in f(): " + str(a)
    g()
```

to print out the global `a` use it this way:

```
def f():
    print a
    new_a = a
    print new_a
```

There is a good example about `global` [**`here`**](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-you-set-a-global-variable-in-a-function.htm)

And if you want to use local variable `a` with value from global `a` use [**`globals`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals):

```
def g():  
    a = globals()['a']
    a += 1
    print "in g(): " + str(a)
```

Comment: In your second piece of code you don't need `global`

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the `global` keyword.

```
>>> a = 1         
>>> def g():      
...     global a  
...     a += 1    
...     print a   
...               
>>> g()           
2
```

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the global operative in the function g and f
 like this:

```
a = 1

def g():
    global a
    a += 1
    print "in g(): " + str(a)

def f():
    global a
    a += 1
    print "in f(): " + str(a)
```

You can find more on global and local variables in the [documentation here](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python) and from [stack overflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them)

Answer (score 1):

When you ask for a variable value, Python follows [LEGB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/292502/5338270) rule: local, enclosing, global, built-in.

But when you assign a variable, it is created **from scratch** in the local scope (assuming the variable assignment is inside function), discarding whatever value was previously bound to it:

```
a = 5
def f(x):
   print a  # Prints `5`, because name `a` can be found following LEGB rule in Global scope.
   print x  # Prints whatever value `x` was having, found following LEGB rule in Local scope.
   x = 123  # Forgets previous value of `x`, re-assign it to `123` in the Local scope.
```

Your problem with unbound variable appears here: `a += 1` is simply a syntactic sugar for `a = a + 1`. When you do `a = a + 1`, Python catches that `a` is local , so it produces LOAD_FAST command in bytecode:

```
import dis
a = 1
def f():
  a += 1
print dis.dis(f)

          0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
          3 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
          6 INPLACE_ADD
          7 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
         10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
         13 RETURN_VALUE
```

LOAD_FAST is used for local variable fetching. But you do not have `a` in local scope yet when LOAD_FAST is called, so the command fails.

Actually, if you do not assign to `a`, but want to modify it from local scope, you can do it via method calls. Unfortunately, `int` don't have modifying methods, so I'll give an example with class:

```
class Number(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def add_one(self):
        self.x += 1

a = Number(1)
def f():
    a.add_one()
    print a.x


print a.x
f()
print a.x

1
2
2
```

Here you essentially do `a=a+1`, but in a more complicated manner. This is because calls to `a` are resolved as Global (and work fine) and you don't do any assignments inside `f()`. Method `add_one` is called on existing object - it does not care whether it was global or local in the caller.